# Child state not waiting from parent resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lazy-loading, resolve

I have a parent state which in its resolve loads a JavaScript file (say abc.js). All child state's controllers are defined in that abc.js file. So it is obvious that I want all child state to be resolved after parent is done loading abc.js. Please find my snippet below -

```
    .state('parent', {
        url: '/role',
        templateUrl: 'something.tmpl.html',
        resolve: {
            loadRoleScript: function() {
                var injector = angular.injector(['ng']),
                    q = injector.get('$q'),
                    deferred = q.defer(),
                    scriptTag = '';

                scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
                scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
                scriptTag.src = 'path/to/js/file/abc.js';
                scriptTag.onload = scriptTag.onreadystatechange = function(_, isAbort) {
                    if (!scriptTag.readyState || /loaded|complete/.test(scriptTag.readyState)) {
                        if (isAbort) {
                            deferred.reject();
                        } else {
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                // Here goes some of my logic
                                console.log('Parent resolved');
                                deferred.resolve();
                            }, 100);
                        }
                    }
                };
                scriptTag.onerror = function() {
                    deferred.reject();
                };
                document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
            }
        }
    })
    .state('parent.dashboard', {
        url: '/roledashboard',
        controller: 'RoleHomeCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'something/child.tmpl.html',
        resolve: {
            dependent1: ['loadRoleScript', function(loadRoleScript) {
                console.log('child getting loaded before parent is resolved');
            }]
        }
    });
```

**Output I am getting on console** -

child getting loaded before parent is resolved.

Parent resolved.

I have followed multiple links like this -
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1903
but solutions suggested everywhere is not working for me.

$ocLazyLoad is also an option but trying to implement by myself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to modify your code to be like this:

```
 .state('parent', {
        url: '/role',
        templateUrl: 'something.tmpl.html',
        resolve: {
            loadRoleScript: function() {
                var injector = angular.injector(['ng']),
                    q = injector.get('$q'),
                    deferred = q.defer(),
                    scriptTag = '';

                scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
                scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
                scriptTag.src = 'path/to/js/file/abc.js';
                scriptTag.onload = scriptTag.onreadystatechange = function(_, isAbort) {
                    if (!scriptTag.readyState || /loaded|complete/.test(scriptTag.readyState)) {
                        if (isAbort) {
                            deferred.reject();
                        } else {
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                // Here goes some of my logic
                                console.log('Parent resolved');
                                deferred.resolve();
                            }, 100);
                        }
                    }
                };
                scriptTag.onerror = function() {
                    deferred.reject();
                };
                document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
                // !!
                // !!
                return deferred.promise;
                // !!
                // !!

            }
        }
    })
 .state('dashboard', {
        parent:'parent',
        url: '/roledashboard',
        controller: 'RoleHomeCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'something/child.tmpl.html',
        resolve: {
            dependent1: function(loadRoleScript) {
                console.log('child getting loaded before parent is resolved');
            }
        }
    });
```

Then resolving of the parent state should be done correctly

Comment: Thanks for the response but tried that too. No luck :/

Comment: @kamalkokne That is somewhat strange.  One other thing that is different in my code is that I use parent:'parent' property for the state instead of name resolution. see the edit.

Comment: Tried with parent: 'parent' also but still same error. First child getting printed.

Comment: @kamalkokne ahh... you have a different problem here (or as well). Your parent resolver is actually async. You need to return the promise from the deffered object for it not to resolve instantly. see the edit